# How to check if a given surface is a plane surface

Tags: linear-algebra

As title says, how to check if the following surface:

$$
S:
\begin{cases}
x = (u-v)^2 \\ y= u^2 - 3v^2 \\ z = \frac{v}{2}(u - 2v)
\end{cases}
$$

is a plane surface (or flat).

Sorry for my english, but I couldn't find a better translation.

Comment: a plane has the form $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$ where $a,b,c,d$$ are real numbers

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner In this case $d=0$.

Comment: from where do you know this?

Comment: @altair2033 What definition of "flat" are you shooting for? is it enough to know it can be written in some standard algebraic form that you know planes can be written in? Include this information in the post.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner For $u=v=0$ we get $x=y=z=0$, so the surface goes through the origin of the coordinate system. If it is a plane, then the $d$ term of the plane's equation must be zero.

Comment: THIS should go as ANSWER, alas due to the 'on hold' status I can only post it as a comment: _If you carefully eliminate $u^2$ and $v^2$ and $u\cdot v$ from your three equations, you'll get $$x - y + 4z = 0$$ which is an equation of a plane. So $S$ is a subset of the plane—and you only need to show that every point of the plane can be described by appropriate $(u,v)$ pair, that is that $S$ actually is a whole plane._

Answer (score 1):

Find the normal vector to the parametrized surface in the usual way:  After some calculation get $T_\mathbf{u} \times T_\mathbf{v} = (u^2-4uv+3v^2)\langle 1, -1, 4 \rangle.$  Since the normal vector to the surface always points in the same direction, you have a plane surface.